# How can i disable a method when running in test mode in Spring?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a method looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = ["/signup"],
        consumes = [(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)])
fun signUp(@RequestBody dto: RegistrationDto)
        : ResponseEntity<Void> {

    val userId : String = dto.userInfo!!.username!!
    val password : String = dto.password!!

    val registered = if(!dto.secretPassword.isNullOrBlank() && dto.secretPassword.equals(adminCode)) {
        authService.createUser(userId, password, setOf("ADMIN"))
    } else {
        authService.createUser(userId, password, setOf("USER"))
    }

    if (!registered) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(400).build()
    }

    val userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userId)
    val token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.authorities)

    authenticationManager.authenticate(token)

    if (token.isAuthenticated) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = token
    }

    /**
     * AMQP
     */
    amqpService.send(dto.userInfo!!, "USER-REGISTRATION")

    return ResponseEntity.status(204).build()
}
```

If you notice i have a method `amqpService.send(dto.userInfo!!, "USER-REGISTRATION`, how can i disable this method when i am running in "development" mode ?

I want to disable RabbiqMQ when running in test mode so this method dont get called?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test mode you can replace the amqpService on a mock:

```
@Configuration
public class AmqpConfig {

   @Profile("test")
   @Bean 
   public AmqpService amqpService(){
     return mock(AmqpService.class);
   }   
}
```

Or you can use `@MockBean` immediately in your test class to replace this bean on the mock in tests.

So you run a method of mock instead of a real object.